# Finding efficient working days from begin and end of month from a csv file

Tags: ruby, csv, datetime

I downloaded a historical data of the DAX from [Yahoo Finance website](https://de.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=%5EGDAXI).

My goal was to find out the return yield over a period time like Sell in May or Sell in Summer.

At the moment I get frustrated by handling the date correctly.

The CVS list using the newest date at the top:

```
    Date
    2015-08-31
    2015-08-28
    2015-08-27
```

The script is running through each CSV line. Which works well for the end of the month because it will be the first one. But it won't work if it's searching for the begin of the month because it finds the first occurrence which is often the fourth.

```
    2015-08-06
    2015-08-05 
    2015-08-04
    2015-08-03
```

I try it with a Ruby script, here the code:

```
require 'csv'

year = Time.new.year

start_month = "11"
end_month = "04"

search_format = "%s-%s-%s"

table = CSV.read('table.csv')

complete = []
period = []

table.each do |day_result|

    if period.empty? and day_result[0].include? search_format % [year, end_month, "30"]
        puts "Found date " + search_format % [year, end_month, "30"]
        period.push(day_result[0])
        period.push(day_result[1])
        year = year - 1
    elsif period.empty? and day_result[0].include? search_format % [year, end_month, "29"]
        puts "Found date " + search_format % [year, end_month, "29"]
        period << day_result[0]
        period << day_result[1]
        year = year - 1
   elsif period.empty? and day_result[0].include? search_format % [year, end_month, "28"]
        puts "Found date " + search_format % [year, end_month, "28"]
        period << day_result[0]
        period << day_result[1]
        year = year - 1
    end

    if period.size == 2 and day_result[0].include? search_format % [year, start_month, "01"]
        puts "Found date " + search_format % [year, start_month, "01"]
        period.unshift(day_result[1])
        period.unshift(day_result[0])
        complete.push(period.clone)
        period.clear
    elsif period.size == 2 and day_result[0].include? search_format % [year, start_month, "02"]
        puts "Found date " + search_format % [year, start_month, "02"]
        period.unshift(day_result[1])
        period.unshift(day_result[0])
        complete.push(period.clone)
        period.clear
    elsif period.size == 2 and day_result[0].include? search_format % [year, start_month, "03"]
        puts "Found date " + search_format % [year, start_month, "03"]
        period.unshift(day_result[1])
        period.unshift(day_result[0])
        complete.push(period.clone)
        period.clear
    elsif period.size == 2 and day_result[0].include? search_format % [year, start_month, "04"]
        puts "Found date " + search_format % [year, start_month, "04"]
        period.unshift(day_result[1])
        period.unshift(day_result[0])
        complete.push(period.clone)
        period.clear
    end
end
```

In this example the code is searching the period from 01.11.xx to 31.04.xy.

One thing where I'm not sure is that the date are strings. One solution could be to take the first occurrence of October but I see some growing complexity since I have in my mind even the monthly any yearly return to calculate

Is there an efficient and reliable way to scan a CSV list in Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

you are going to have a hard time doing this right.

would recommend looking at beginning_of_month in rails / active support gem.

the way I would do this if implementing it from scratch, is that I would read all of the dates, convert them to epoch time, sort, pick the smallest and the largest, and after that keep adding (or removing) 1 day and converting back to date until the month changes.